# on 1989 f350, after turning ignition on to crank position, turn key to off and remove key, starter continues to crank . what is sticking?

Tags: ford, starting, f-350

After inserting key and turning to start position, starter continues to crank after engine starts. You can turn ignition off and remove key and starter continues to crank. have replaced solenoid, ignition tumblers and starter. What could be sticking to cause starter to continue to crank?

Comment: If you disconnect the battery and reconnect it, does the starter run straight away?

Comment: yes, if you reconnect battery, the starter does run. i did not replace the switch, just the tumblers.

Answer (score 2):

When you say you have replaced the ignition tumblers, I am presuming you have replaced the electricial switch on the back of tumblers, so let's forget about that.

Seeing as you need to initiate this by turning the key, it can't be a short somewhere.

If the starter is indeed being powered at this point, the only thing left that could cause this is the starter relay in the fuse box.

--UPDATE--

Since you didn't replace the switch, then the switch is also possibly faulty.  For simplicity I would first try swapping the starter relay in the fuse box for an identical one if there is one.  If that doesn't fix it, then the next thing to change would be the ignition switch.

Comment: I 2nd this. If the starter relay is malfunctioning, the circuit will be stuck closed so it will continue to try to engage your starter. Being an '89 it doesn't have any advanced computer systems to get in the way. Could it possibly be the ignition switch itself though??

Comment: @cloudnyn3  He said that he has replaced the 'tumbers', I am presuming he meant the whole thing including the switch.